# MYSQL Select from table, get newest/last 10 rows in table

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

What's the best, and easiest way to do this?  My query currently is:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM chat 
   WHERE (userID = $session AND toID = $friendID) 
      OR (userID = $friendID AND toID = $session) 
ORDER BY id 
   LIMIT 10
```

This shows the first 10 rows though, not the last 10.

EDIT: I Want the last 10 rows (Which yes, DESC does this) However I want them to be returned in ASCENDING order.

Comment: Use the **sort** option on the database.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

to reverse the order (therefore get last 10 instead of first 10), use `DESC` instead of `ASC`

**EDIT**

Based on your comment:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM chat 
  WHERE (userID = $session AND toID = $friendID) 
    OR (userID = $friendID AND toID = $session)  
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 10
) AS `table` ORDER by id ASC
```

Comment: I forgot to include in my question, I want the last 10 rows (yes using DESC), but in Asc order.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but this is just what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last 10 then just change ASC to DESC

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
chat 
WHERE 
(userID=$session AND toID=$friendID) 
OR 
(userID=$friendID AND toID=$session) 
ORDER BY id 
DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot to include in my question, the last 10 (which yes can be done with DESC, but in ASC order.

Answer (score 1):

First select the last 10 from the table, then re-order them in ascending order.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) sub ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$limit = 10;                
$query = "SELECT * FROM  $table";
$resource = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($resource);
$start = $total_rows-$limit;
$query_limit= $query." LIMIT $start,$limit";
```

First I have set the limit

```
$limit = 10;
```

then

```
 $total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($resource);
```

Here I have taken total number of rows affected.

```
$start = $total_rows-$limit;
```

then substracted limit from number of rows to take starting record number

```
   $query_limit= $query." LIMIT $start,$limit";
```

and then added limit to the query.
For more information about limit see this link
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Comment: Code dumps without explanation are rarely helpful. Please add some context to your answer.

Comment: This could be an issue if you have a filter. some data could be ignored.

Comment: @Chris Is it okay...? I have added little explanation to the answer

Comment: @mohitesachin217, you've added some explanation, but you're using the ancient `mysql_*` functions in your answer. If you're writing new code, **_please_ don't use the `mysql_*` functions**. They are old and broken, were deprecated in PHP 5.5 (which is so old it no longer even receives security updates), and completely removed in PHP 7. Use [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with _prepared statements_ and _parameter binding_ instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/354577 for details.